# Problems using Julia's unsafe_wrap on data supplied by Cxx.jl

Tags: c++, julia

As the title suggests, I've run into very puzzling behavior with Cxx and unsafe_wrap(). I've got some c++ code that returns `vector<vector<uint8_t>>&` which I'm viewing in Julia. I can perform the same operation twice in a row and get different answers each time. I've put together a code snippet that demonstrates the behavior I'm seeing:

```
using Cxx

cxx"""
#include <vector>

struct vholder {
    std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>> data;
    vholder() {
        std::vector<float> f1{1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1};
        std::vector<uint8_t> c1(8*sizeof(float));
        std::memcpy(c1.data(), f1.data(), 8*sizeof(float));
        data.push_back(c1);
        std::vector<float> f2{2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2, 2.2};
        std::vector<uint8_t> c2(8*sizeof(float));
        std::memcpy(c2.data(), f2.data(), 8*sizeof(float));
        data.push_back(c2);
        std::vector<float> f3{3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3};
        std::vector<uint8_t> c3(8*sizeof(float));
        std::memcpy(c3.data(), f3.data(), 8*sizeof(float));
        data.push_back(c3);
        std::vector<float> f4{4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4, 4.4};
        std::vector<uint8_t> c4(8*sizeof(float));
        std::memcpy(c4.data(), f4.data(), 8*sizeof(float));
        data.push_back(c4);
    }

    std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>>& get_data() {
        return data;
    }
};

"""

vholder = @cxxnew vholder()
vdata = @cxx vholder->get_data()
jdata = [reinterpret(Complex{Float32}, unsafe_wrap(Array, pointer(v), length(v)))
         for v in vdata]
display(jdata)
jdata = [reinterpret(Complex{Float32}, unsafe_wrap(Array, pointer(v), length(v)))
         for v in vdata]
display(jdata)
```

I've written the C++ part to make it very obvious what the expected result should be after Julia has done its part. When I run the code, this is what I see:

```
4-element Array{Base.ReinterpretArray{Complex{Float32},1,UInt8,Array{UInt8,1}},1}:
 [4.048057f-36 + 0.0f0im, 4.047994f-36 + 0.0f0im, 7.0f-45 + 1.0f-42im, 3.0f-45 + 0.0f0im]  
 [1.7337694f-38 + 0.0f0im, 0.0f0 + 0.0f0im, 1.8f-44 + 0.0f0im, 2.0056614f-36 + 0.0f0im]    
 [1.7337694f-38 + 0.0f0im, 0.0f0 + 0.0f0im, 1.8f-44 + 0.0f0im, 4.664f-42 + 0.0f0im]        
 [6.0541977f-37 + 0.0f0im, 3.1095097f-36 + 0.0f0im, 7.0f-45 + 4.9f-44im, 3.0f-45 + 0.0f0im]
4-element Array{Base.ReinterpretArray{Complex{Float32},1,UInt8,Array{UInt8,1}},1}:
 [1.1f0 + 1.1f0im, 1.1f0 + 1.1f0im, 1.1f0 + 1.1f0im, 1.1f0 + 1.1f0im]
 [2.2f0 + 2.2f0im, 2.2f0 + 2.2f0im, 2.2f0 + 2.2f0im, 2.2f0 + 2.2f0im]
 [3.3f0 + 3.3f0im, 3.3f0 + 3.3f0im, 3.3f0 + 3.3f0im, 3.3f0 + 3.3f0im]
 [4.4f0 + 4.4f0im, 4.4f0 + 4.4f0im, 4.4f0 + 4.4f0im, 4.4f0 + 4.4f0im]
```

I set the c++ code up specifically with the intention of making the lifetime of the object returned longer than Julia's need to examine it, but may have failed at this.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround that addresses my particular needs, but doesn't explain the odd behavior that I ran into. If I add `std::vector<uint8_t>& get_channel() { return vdata[0]; }` as a method, and call:

```
vholder = @cxxnew vholder()
channelVals = @cxx vholder->get_channel()
jvals = reinterpret(Complex{Float32},
                    unsafe_wrap(Array, pointer(channelVals), length(channelVals)))
```

I then get the expected results. So there seems to be some issue with iterating over the outer vector. I'm still curious about that, so I'm not going to accept my own answer (at least for now).